# In Node.js using Express, how does one have a user login along with admin login? I want users limited access with admin have access to all routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, admin

I built out a Node app with a user login and all the routes are protected for only users. Now I'd like to take that a step further and have one login for users and admin, but once logged in the user has access to particular routes while the admin has access to all. Here's a snippet of what I currently have:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(session({
    store: new pgSession({
        pgPromise: db
    }),
    secret: 'abc123',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
    }
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// protected route function for all users
function protectRoute(req, res, next) {
    let isLoggedIn = req.session.user ? true : false;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/search')
    }
}

//middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let isLoggedIn = req.session.user ? true : false; 
    next();
});

//login
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.send(page(loginForm()));
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const theUsername = req.body.username;
    const thePassword = req.body.password;

    User.getUserByUsername(theUsername)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/login');
        })
        .then(theUser => {
            if(theUser.password === thePassword){
                req.session.user = theUser;
                req.session.save(function(err){
                    res.redirect('/search');
                });
            } else {
                res.redirect('/login');
            }
        })

})

// search page for all users and admin
app.get('/search', protectRoute, (req, res) => {
    res.send(page(companySearchForm(), req.session.user));
});

// inactive list that I WANT FOR ONLY ADMIN but currently for all users
app.get('/inactivelist', protectRoute, (req, res) => {
    Company.getCompanyByStatus(false)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .then(theCompany => {
            const companyInfo = inactiveList(theCompany);
            const thePage = page(companyInfo, req.session.user);
            res.send(thePage);
        })
})
```

Here's the page view function that checks if loggedIn

```
const {logoutButton, loginOrRegister} = require('./helper');

function page(content, isLoggedIn=false){
    return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/index.css">

        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${
            isLoggedIn ? logoutButton() : loginOrRegister()
        }
        <div>
            ${content}
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    `
}

module.exports = page;
```

So as you can see all users have access to all protected routes. How would I make that so users get access to certain paths and admins have access to all? In my PostgreSQL database there's a column on users that's admin_access boolean default 'FALSE'. Here's the database users table schema:

```
create table users (
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    username text,
    password text,
    admin_access boolean default 'FALSE'
);
```

I know it's a lot but I'd appreciate the help. No clue how admin access would work.

Comment: 1. during login processing: `req.session.admin = theUser.admin_access;`, this way you can check the user level at any point 2. whenever you're rendering a page or making a database operation, check `req.session.admin` first. You have all this in place already, since you're using the *exact same* mechanism to do the login check. (btw, try using a template engine like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) instead of sending back cobbled together HTML, it makes things a lot easier and smoother)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use another middleware function such as the following

```js
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    // Check if the requesting user is marked as admin in database
    let isAdmin = // check in database
    if (isAdmin) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/search')
    }
}
```

and then I'd use it this way

```js
// inactive list that I WANT FOR ONLY ADMIN but currently for all users
app.get('/inactivelist', protectRoute, isAdmin, (req, res) => {
    Company.getCompanyByStatus(false)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .then(theCompany => {
            const companyInfo = inactiveList(theCompany);
            const thePage = page(companyInfo, req.session.user);
            res.send(thePage);
        })
})
```

for every route that actually requires you being an admin in order to use it

Comment: This is what I'd do too. Two further suggestions if the OP is relatively new to node/Express: 1) consult the docs at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html 2) A query against a database is almost certainly going to be asynchronous, so with a promise-based interface `let isAdmin = ...` will actually always grant permission, as Promises are truthy. The OP should be careful to make this async.

Comment: would I need to add another app.use() or add isAdmin into the app.use()? As for checking isAdmin in the database I keep getting back undefined. Would I need to first define admin_access in the login section?

Comment: The reason for the undefined may actually be the second bullet pointed out by @rwold. Check out async functions and promises as suggested for that

Comment: @Kllicks If you add another app.use(), every route in your app will check to see if they are an admin. You probably want to go with Lykos94's suggestion, which is to include it in specific routes only. See the docs I linked to above for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.restrictTo = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return res.status(403).json({
        status : 'fail',
        message : 'You dont have permession'
      });
    }
    next();
  };
};
```

In the route file call it as middleware

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('./../controllers/userController');
const { protect ,restrictTo} = require('./../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();


router
  .route('/')
  .post( protect , restrictTo("admin") ,userController.createUser);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).